# How to declare and call a java method which takes two dimensional bye array parameter from RPG?

Tags: java, arrays, primitive-types, rpgle, rpg

I have a java method one of whose arguments is a 2 dimensional byte array (`byte[][]`). I wanted to call that method from RPG. I know that it works for one dimensional byte array e.g. by declaring that argument in RPG as nA where n is the length of the array and A is Alphabetic. i.e. nA in RPG is same as `byte[]` in java. However when I add DIM(k) to the argument declaration RPG, it says Keyword is not allowed in a prototype of a method. 
I could do it using String data type but I wanted to avoid data type conversions like  from bytes to java String and vice-versa. (efficiency issues)

Can anyone help me with getting it work, please?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the way to go here from a code-compileability and readability perspective is to use a simple data-wrapper class holding a one-dimensional array, and then let your main-code use a one-dimensional array of instances of said data-wrapper class.

```
public class MyBytePacket
{
    private byte [] data;

    //Constructors and getters as needed
}
```

And then from main code;

```
MyBytePacket [] packets = new MyBytePacket[10];
```

That way, you can see how many packets you have, as well as how many bytes each packet has, keeping your desired 2D-aspect, but in a more Java-friendly manner.

Comment: Just realized that I'm probably answering the wrong question here. My bad.

Comment: Hi @Markus, you are answering the right question. I thank you for your answer and will give it a try. I think making the private byte array two dimensional and then using one object of the wrapper class in the main code will also be good. I will get back to you with the results.

Comment: @tewemit, happy to hear ;) Hope things work out for you.

Comment: Hi @Marcus, I am able to pass my bytes from JAVA to RPG program but when I see the characters in RPG, they became strange chars like this: ëèè .. It seems I am missing some kind of byte conversion. Does anyone have any advice here, please.

Comment: What do you mean by "see" in RPG? Are you printing/displaying them? Interpreting them as chars/ASCII? What does your bytes represent? I used "packets" as conceptual explanation entity in my code above, but what are your bytes representing, really?